# How to find empty or NULL column value in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I need to find and update the status id if the specific columns are empty or NULL.

I need to check columns Like Phone and Email if its value is empty or NULL, the Status should be updated to 2.

[image: UserTbl]

I tried this query:

```sql
select * from UserTbl where NULL in(Email, Phone)
```

As the column values are empty, I am not getting any result.

Comment: What is your DBMS product? Oracle? Mysql? Postgres? SQL Server?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Its SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```sql
UPDATE UserTbl
SET StatusId=2 
WHERE 
      (ISNULL(Phone) OR Phone='')
  AND (ISNULL(Email) OR Email='');
```

Comment: Is there any other way because there might be More columns to check the Values,
Like 15 to 20 columns. in that case this query will be biggy.

Comment: Add them to the `WHERE` clause? Maybe create a stored function that checks whether a column is either NULL or equal to the empty string?

Comment: Your Code should be:

UPDATE UserTbl
SET StatusId=2 
WHERE (Phone is NULL OR Phone=' ') 
AND (Email) is NULL OR Email=' ')

Comment: Yes, reading the question carefully I think so too. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
UPDATE <TableName> 
SET StatusId = 2
WHERE (ISNULL(Phone) OR Phone = '') AND (ISNULL(Email) OR Email= '')
```

Comment: Is there any other way because there might be More columns to check the Values, Like 15 to 20 columns. in that case,

Comment: @PKJI Why cant you copy-paste it 15-20 times?